# Can I search for a user name? Cannot find them

Tags: discussion

I think their name was 'Olivia' or sjmilar? Can anyone link to the questions and answers? I can't recall exactly any question I can find that they answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go on the [user site](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all&search=olivia). It works better than the general search.

Comment: thanks. seems not to exist etc